# Etherscan returns values of 0 instead correct amount! (same thing for bscscan)

Tags: etherscan, api

I have this query. Result should be amount of tokens DEXT in wallet. It returns 0.

Yesterday was working fine. (???)

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0xfb1b36bef010d6b073d35d40cf3069ad0d1d153a&address=0x994ccc92858c20aed7a4c0400ce1ac0c43f3e587&tag=latest&apikey=my-key

Answer (score 1):

The contract address you have supplied in the api call `0xfb1b36bef010d6b073d35d40cf3069ad0d1d153a` is not a contract address rather it is a wallet address. The correct contract address for DEXT token in ethereum chain is `0xfB7B4564402E5500dB5bB6d63Ae671302777C75a`. The address `0x994cCc92858c20AED7A4C0400ce1AC0c43f3E587` does not contain any ERC20 token. The correct api call for wallet containing DEXT token is below:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0xfB7B4564402E5500dB5bB6d63Ae671302777C75a&address=0x67e8472cbfae3824f5e2e57fdcdcefd2409c6305&tag=latest
```